# Insert a string in a column, then assign a relation in anothre column

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm stuck with a task I thought simple, and hope it's actually simple :)

I have to insert a string (this is an image file name) in a table, called "images";
I have another table which is called "projects";
And a third table with the relation between "images" and "projects" which is called "imagesRel";

I want to insert the string in "images" and at the same time, assign its auto-incremental id to an auto-incremental id (which I knew before) of the table "projects" in the "imagesRel" as relation.

Which MySql command have I to use?
Is there a JOIN for this insert? I'm stuck because the idImage is yet to be assigned when I make the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using LAST_INSERT_ID() function

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL

INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```

See more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using LAST_INSERT_ID() to get last inserted ID